# Figure out if bit in unsigned short is set or not

Tags: c, bit

well Figure out if bit in unsigned short is set or not. so Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise. Also I have to remember that the bits are numbered 0 from the right: like b15b14b13 ... b3b2b1b0. Well I tried like that but I think it did not work ...Any help will appreciated.

```
short is_set(unsigned short x, int bit) {
return (x >> bit) & 1;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think your solution is incorrect?

Comment: How i can check this function?! @Eric

Comment: @Manuel Your answer is right.

Comment: First, think about it. You first shift off the lowest `bit` bits of `x`. Now the `bit`th bit is the least significant bit. When you `& 1`, this selects out only the least significant bit of `x`. Since the least significant bit is the one you want, your function is correct. Once you have reasoned it through, try it on some inputs and do a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

```
short is_set(unsigned short x, int bit) {

    return ((1 << bit) & x);
}
```

valter

Comment: What does this version do differently?

Comment: @Gabe So 5 + 3 is the same as 6 + 2.

Comment: @Manuel Both are correct

Comment: @Gabe Functions differ.  valter_is_set(2,1) returns 2.  Manuel__is_set(2,1) returns 1.  OP wanted  "Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise".

Comment: @Gabe You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well your solution seems to be correct, but to answer why is it not working you should post the cases where it failed.

Till then try this way, and share your observations:

```
short is_set(unsigned short x, int bit) {    
    return (!!((1u << bit) & x));
}
```

Comment: This does not meet OP's "Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise".

Comment: @chux : Corrected it!!

Comment: @Marichyasana `!!` is the `!` operator called twice.  As `(1u << bit) & x` returns values like `0,1,2,4,8,...` calling `!` on it returns `1,0,0,0,0,...`.  Calling it twice returns `0,1,1,1,1,...`, thus correctly matching OP goal of "Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise"

Answer (score 0):

Create test cases as suggested by @Eric and @MadHatter:

```
void Test(short x, int i, int expect) {
  printf("Expect %d, is_set(%#x,%d) --> ", expect, x,i);
  fflush(stdout);  // Flush output as is_set() may fail.
  int result = is_set(x,i);
  printf(" %d,  %s\n", result, expect == result ? "Success" : "Fail");
}

void Tests(void) {
  Test(0x0000, 0, 0);
  Test(0x0001, 0, 1);
  Test(0x1234, 2, 1);
  Test(0x1234, 3, 0);
  // etc.
}
Expect 0, is_set(0,0) -->  0,  Success
Expect 1, is_set(0x1,0) -->  1,  Success
Expect 1, is_set(0x1234,2) -->  1,  Success
Expect 0, is_set(0x1234,3) -->  0,  Success
```

---

The function correctly performs "Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise".

Minor: Match the code naming to the requirement.

```
// Return 1 iff bit i in x is set, 0 otherwise
//                                 v 
short is_set(unsigned short x, int i) {
```

Minor: The return values are 1 and 0.  This should imply `int` unless otherwise stated.

```
int is_set(unsigned short x, int i) {
```